# SQL Performance from .net: Insert via loop vs XML vs Sql Data Table Type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a handful of records, 5-10, that I need to take from the user and run a SQL merge statement against.  I can think of three ways of accomplishing this.

- .net Loop processing one record at a time - Wondering what the performance of this would be compared to the other options.  I would think it is pretty good given connection pooling?
- SQL Data Table type - I have seen these used elsewhere in the project, but as I learned first hand these are a pain to update the table definitions if need, dropping the entire object and recreating
- XML variable - I have used this in the past.  I like it because it is flexible to change the definition of the object.  The .net is simple with XMLSerializer.  But I am sure there is probably a performance hit to call XMLSerializer.  And then on the SQL side to use the .nodes() function.

Does anyone know by personal experience or some reference, such as a white paper, which method is the most efficient when inserting/updating records in a database via .net application?

Comment: I agree TVPs can be a pain to maintain if you don't leverage tools to generate a deployment script (SSDT, RedGate) but it can be very efficient with attention to detail.

Comment: TVP need to creating DataTable on the side of C# client, and it's really slow (much slower than inserting record into DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 5-10 items you can use "clasic" insert with more records.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
    (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
    VALUES
    (@ColumnA_0, @ColumnB_0, @ColumnC_0),
    (@ColumnA_1, @ColumnB_1, @ColumnC_1),
    (@ColumnA_2, @ColumnB_2, @ColumnC_2)
```

This is MUCH faster than XML or DataTable. And is faster than isolated inserts in loop.

The limit for number of inserted records is 1000. If you want more, you need execute more statements.

Comment: Note that there is a limitation of 2100 parameters per command so a parameterized query may hit that restriction before the 1000 row constructor limit.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain this well but the amount of rows will be variable, so I don't want to pass in 45-50 variables I don't need even if they are optional.  Unless you are suggestion running the statement directly in the app and building the string on the fly.  In which case that just becomes a loop again to create the string from a collection.

Comment: The loop in .net environment is not slow (but not in t-sql). Use StringBuilder for that. If you want something super-fast, you can cache the generated statement strings for each table instead of creating new instances.